# Static library included, but symbols unresolved

Tags: makefile, autoconf, automake

Under automake, I have a third party static library and a static library I am building on top of it, which I want to use in executables statically linked with my library:

```
libthird.a, libmy.a, progs...
```

I am compiling libmy.a with (Makefile.am):

```
noinst_LIBRARIES = libmy.a
...sources...
libmy_a_LIBADD = libthird.a
```

When I compile and link a prog that calls libmy functions, it refuses to link, giving unresolved errors on all libthird symbols used by libmy.

As a try, I replaced

```
libmy_a_LIBADD = libthird.a
```

with

```
libmy_a_LIBADD = $(LIB_THIRD_OBJS)
```

i.e. explicitly the object files from which libthird.a is constructed, and it works. What am I doing wrong in the first case? libmy.a contains libthird.a in the first case (i.e. `less libmy.a` shows object files and libthird.a)

As another try, I ran `ar` on libmy.a, feeding it libthird.a, to produce libmyA.a, and that works as well: progs linked with libmyA.a have libthird symbols properly resolved.

Or is it not even possible, as (I think) explained here: [Embed all external references when creating a static library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12195000/embed-all-external-references-when-creating-a-static-library) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not:

```
prog_LDADD = libmy.a libthird.a
```

you should also omit:

```
libmy_a_LIBADD = libthird.a
```

in this case because `libmy.a` is a static convenience library, so there's no real point to further linking it.

Comment: Thanks. My question was not well-put. I edited it to better reflect what I'm doing. What you say would work in the case I described originally, but I need libmy.a to contain libthird symbols, as I'm going to link programs against it outside the makefile I described.

Comment: Then `libmy.a` probably shouldn't be a convenience library.  You say "I need libmy.a to contain libthird symbols , as I'm going to link programs against it outside the makefile I described."  _Not_ having libthird symbols in your lib won't prevent that -- they'll just link `libmy.a` and `libthird.a`.  Or something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23432530/425738)  to combine your static libs into one lib they can link (as you said you've done).  That's the basic choice you've got with static libs.

Comment: Thanks, the latter is what I'm looking for. As for linking executables with both `libmy.a` and `libthird.a` - this is something I want to avoid, as `libmy.a` is an abstraction above `libthird.a`'s low-level implementation.